# react-intl become formatJs , how re-addlocaledata in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-intl, formatjs

I use react-intl for internationalization and in a component i get and set the locale-data
like that :

```
import fr from 'react-intl/locale-data/fr';
import en from 'react-intl/locale-data/en';
...  
addLocaleData([...fr, ...en]);
```

But the library to migrate to formatJs and I don't see how to do the same with the new syntax or if I need to install something else.
If someone has an idea ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix your issue: https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/upgrade-guide-3x#migrate-to-using-native-intl-apis
For react-native you'd need a bunch of polyfills from https://formatjs.io/docs/polyfills:

- `Intl.getCanonicalLocales`
- `Intl.PluralRules`
- `Intl.NumberFormat`
- `Intl.DateTimeFormat`
- `Intl.RelativeTimeFormat`

Comment: Sorry for my late response .... 
what if I want to add these locales to the IntlProvider for example?  
in fact this is what I did before:  
```import en from 'react-intl / locale-data / en';
import in from 'react-intl / locale-data / en';


addLocaleData ([... fr, ... en]);```

Comment: That's work thx @Long Ho with few adaptation for android ;)